# apache hadoop, hbase and nutch components distribution for 4 servers cluster

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive, hbase, nutch

I have 4 systems. I want to crawl some data. For that first I need to configure cluster. I am confused about placement of components.

1. should I place all component (hadoop, hive, hbase, nutch) in one machine and add other machines as nodes in hadoop?
2. Should I place hbase in one machine, nutch in other and hadoop in third and add forth machine as slave of hadoop?
3. Should HBase be in pseudo distributed mode or full distributed.
4. How many slaves I sholud add in hbase if I run it as fully distributed mode.

What should be the best way. PLease guide step by step ( For hbase and hadoop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have 4 nodes n1, n2, n3 and n4.
You can install hadoop and hbase in distributed mode.
If you are using Hadoop 1.x -

```
n1 - hadoop master[Namenode and Jobtracker]
n2, n3 and n3 - hadoop slaves [datanodes and tasktrackers]
```

For HBase, you can choose n1 or any other node as Master node, Since Master node are usually not CPU/Memory intensive, all Masters can be deployed on single node on test setup, However in Production its good to have each Master deployment on a separate node.

```
Lets say n2 - HBase Master, remaining 3 nodes can act as regionservers.
```

Hive and Nutch can reside on any node.
Hope this helps; For a test setup this should be good to go.

---

Update -

For Hadoop 2.x, since your cluster size is small, Namenode HA deployment can be skipped.
Namenode HA would require two nodes one each for an active and standby node.

A zookeeper quorum which again requires odd number of nodes so a minimum of three nodes would be required.

A journal quorum again require a minimum of 3 nodes.

But for a cluster this small HA might not be a major concern. So you can keep

> n1 - namenode
>
> n2 - ResouceManager or Yarn

and remaining nodes can act as datanodes, try not to deploy anything else on the yarn node.

Rest of the deployment for HBase, Hive and Nutch would remain same.

Comment: My hadoop version is 2.x

Comment: Is this your test setup?

Comment: No, It is not for testing only but for actual use also

Comment: Sorry, by mistake I awarded bounty to second answer that cannot be undone. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should install Hadoop in fully distributed mode, so the jobs could run in parallel manner and much faster, as the MapReduce tasks will be distributed in 4 machines. Of course, the Hadoop's master node should run in one single machine.

If you need to process big amount of data, it's a good choice to install HBase in one single machine and the Hadoop in 3.

You could make all the above very easy using tools/platforms with a very friendly GUI like Cloudera Manager and Hortonworks. They will help you to control and maintain your cluster better but they are also provide Health Monitoring, Cluster Analytics as well as E-Mail notifications for every error occurs in your cluster.

Cloudera Manager
http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/products-and-services/cloudera-enterprise/cloudera-manager.html

Hortonworks
http://hortonworks.com/

In these two links, you can find more guidance about how you could costruct your cluster

Comment: Not a comprehensive as asked in question